# Loading Data into Postgreql issue (Looping issue)

Tags: java, hibernate, csv, jdbc, orm

I am trying to load data(CSV) into Postgresql.

**Problem:** When I load data from CSV, the parsing is happening well (I am able to see it from Sysout) but when I try to load into the database. I gat the same value 10000 times. (Not different values as I have in CSV). I am unable to diagnose the issue. Please help!

**The following code reads input from CSV:**

```
public class GeneratePeople {
          public Weather createUser() throws IOException {  
            String csvFile = "D:\\chick.csv";
            BufferedReader br = null;
            String line = "";
            String cvsSplitBy = ",";
            Weather u = new Weather();       
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                      // use comma as separator
            String[] wdata1 = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
                      //System.out.println("Data inserted Before:" +wdata1[4]);
            u.setMnet(wdata1[4]);
                  //System.out.println("Data inserted After:" +wdata1[4]);
                }
                return u;

          }
}
```

**This is my application:**

**This reads the data and Pushes into PostGresql**

```
public class Populate extends People {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Loading data to pplhib");
        Populate p = new Populate();
        p.bulkGenerate(10000);
        System.out.println("!!!!Process Completed!!!!");
    }
    public void bulkGenerate(int count) throws IOException {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        try {
            GeneratePeople gen = new GeneratePeople();
            Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
            for (int n = 0; n < count; n++) {
                Weather p = gen.createUser();
                session.save(p);
                if (n % 100 == 0) {
                    session.flush();
                    session.clear();
                }
            }
            tx.commit();
        } finally {
            // session.close();
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the same value 10,000 times as opposed to different values but the sysout which I have used in generate people shows different values (as expected). Where am I going wrong?

How can I return the value I got from `u.setMnet(wdata1[4]);` before it exits the while loop? Why Am I getting the same value in postgresql?

Thanks!

Comment: PostgreSQL has perfect built-in CSV load - copy statement. It can be 100x faster, than repeated INSERT.

Comment: Isn't your createUser function opening csv file, reading all rows and always returning last row?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Looks like you are right. But I'm unsure how I can solve this.. Should I use array? Can someone shed some light?